# C#: DataBase Null in RadioButtonList

Tags: c#, asp.net

I would like to have a radiobuttollist were you can select value null.

Something like this:

```
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="rblCD" runat="server" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("tblCD") %>'>
           <asp:ListItem Value="RW">RW</asp:ListItem>
           <asp:ListItem Value="R">R</asp:ListItem>
           <asp:ListItem Value="DBNull">None</asp:ListItem>
 </asp:RadioButtonList>
```

Thanks a lot,
Vincent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

THe values in a radiobuttonlist are always strings.  You would have to do something like this

```
<asp:ListItem Value="">None</asp:ListItem>
```

Then when you read the data from the control do something like

```
if (rblCD.SelectedValue == string.Empty)
{
    MyDataRow["Column"] = DBNull.Value;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

yo should use:

```
<asp:RadioButtonList runat=server ID="rd" 
SelectedValue='<%# Eval("myField").GetType() == typeof(DBNull) ? null : Eval("myField") %>'>
           <asp:ListItem Text="yes" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
           <asp:ListItem Text="no" Value="2"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:RadioButtonList>
```

Answer (score 0):

yes you can do , in your example

```
if(rblCD.SelectedValue== "DBNull")
{
     DataRow["Column"] = DbNull.Value;
}
```